# Set html text field value from java interface android

Tags: android, javascript

I am working on a project where i have to set value in html form field from my java method .
In this app when form load i have to fill text field value on user speech.SO what i can do this using JavaScriptInterface in android.
                                       Thanks

Comment: yes you can use javascriptinterface

Answer (score 4):

> MainActivity.java

```
webView.loadUrl("Your URL");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:setTextField("+value+")");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }
        });
```

> HtmlFile.html

```
<script>

        function setTextField(value){
        document.getElementById("texta").value = value;
        }

        </script>
```