# Android: How to add text into TextField WebView

Tags: java, android, html, string, webview

I'm creating a app in which I need to enter data stored in a String to a textfield (textbox) on a website.

Here is the HTML code of that website. Plz not that I don't own the website so I can't make changes in code of the website -

```
<div id="form">
<form method="get" action="/" id="submit-form">

  <input type="text" id="youtube-url" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE" onclick="sAll(this)" autocomplete="off" style="width:466px;" /> 

<!-- Need to add string in value field of above line -->      

  <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:3px">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Convert Video" style="float:none; width:175px" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to enter my url into the value field.

What I tried so far -

```
String protocol = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbGs_qK2PQA";
//this is the url which has to be entered in the value field

web.loadUrl("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/");
//opening the url video converting website   

web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('submit-form').value+='"+protocol+"'");
//adding the url to the value field
```

I am aware of the fact that this type of question has been asked before but the solutions given didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826811/set-html-text-field-value-from-java-interface-android ?

Comment: Yes I just tried it but it didn't seem to work. I can't add the HTML snippet to my website as I don't own it.

Comment: Is there any alternative method which I can use?

Comment: Have you got the answer? I am also facing same issue.